# Play IMA ADPCM Audio with NAudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, naudio, adpcm

I have a file with no header with IMA ADPCM raw data stored, I would like to play it using NAudio.
In Audacity, using this config plays without problems:

```
Encoding: VOX ADPCM 
Byte order: No Endianness
Channels: 1 Channel (Mono)
Start offset: 0 bytes
Amount to import: 100%
Sample rate: 22050Hz
```

This is the code I'm using, but I always get a **System.DivideByZeroException** error.

```
internal void PlayIMAAudio(WaveOut AudioPlayer, byte[] IMAData, int Frequency, int Bits, int Channels)
{
    if (AudioPlayer.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
    {
        MemoryStream AudioSample = new MemoryStream(IMAData);
        ImaAdpcmWaveFormat FileFormat = new ImaAdpcmWaveFormat(Frequency, Channels, Bits);
        RawSourceWaveStream provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, FileFormat);
        AudioPlayer.Init(provider);
        AudioPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

How could I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't usually play compressed formats directly. Pass the `RawSourceWaveStream` into `WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream` to get to PCM. That should work if you have the right codec available on your PC and if you've correctly specified the source WaveFormat